# How set text elements from 2 differents table in custom adapter?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, adapter, settext

There is my class with custom adapater
It's working with date and title. 
Date and title are with table Page and textTag with Table Tag

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter <PageTag> {

        Context context;
        int ressource;
        ArrayList<Page> data ;
        TextView tvTitreList;
        TextView tvDateList;
        TextView tvTagList;
        Page page;

    public MyAdapter(Context context,  ArrayList <PageTag> data ) {
            super(context, 0, data);
        }
```

My getView method.

```
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_list_perso, parent, false);
        }
        tvTitreList = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitre);
        tvDateList = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        tvTagList  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTag);

        tvTitreList.setText(getItem(position).getPage().titrePage);
        tvDateList.setText(getItem(position).getPage().datePage.toString());
        tvTagList.setText(getItem(position).getTag().texteTag);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

My table PageTag

```
public class PageTag {

  Page page ;
  Tag tag ;

public PageTag ( Page page, Tag tag){

        this.page = page;
        this.tag = tag;
    }
    // with getter and setter
```

my ListPageActivity

```
pageMgr  = new PageMgr(this);
            lvList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listPage);
            ArrayList<Page> listPage = pageMgr.getAllPageArray();
            ArrayList<Tag> listTag = pageMgr.getAllTagArray();

           ArrayList<PageTag> pageTag = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 0 ;i < listPage.size() ;i++){
                Page page = listPage.get(i);
                Tag tag = listTag.get(i);
            (cannot resolve method) ==>  pageTag.setPage(page);
                                     ==> pageTag.setTag(tag);
            }
                MyAdapter myAdapt = new MyAdapter(this,pageTag);
                lvList.setAdapter(myAdapt);
```

getAllpageArray method

```
 public ArrayList<Page> getAllPageArray(){

ArrayList <Page> listPageArray = new ArrayList <Page>();
        String rqPage = " SELECT * FROM " + BaseSQLITE.TABLE_PAGE
                        + " JOIN " + BaseSQLITE.TABLE_LIENS_TAG_PAGE
                        + " ON " + BaseSQLITE.TABLE_PAGE+ "." + BaseSQLITE.COL_ID_PAGE + " = " + BaseSQLITE.TABLE_LIENS_TAG_PAGE+ "." + BaseSQLITE.COL_ID_PAGE_LTP
                        + " JOIN " + BaseSQLITE.TABLE_TAG
                        + " ON "+ BaseSQLITE.TABLE_TAG+ "." + BaseSQLITE.COL_ID_TAG + " = " + BaseSQLITE.TABLE_LIENS_TAG_PAGE+ "." + BaseSQLITE.COL_ID_TAG_LTP ;

        Cursor cPage;
        this.open();
        cPage = bdd.rawQuery(rqPage,null);

       Date date;
       long l;
       String titre;

        while (cPage.moveToNext()){

 String titrePage ;
 Date datePage ;

    l = cPage.getLong(2);
    titrePage = cPage.getString(1);
    datePage = new Date(l);
            listPageArray.add(new Page(titrePage,datePage));
        }
        this.close();
        return listPageArray;
    }
```

same thing for getAllTagArray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new Model class

```
class Result{
 Page page;
 Tag tag;
 //getters and setters 
}
```

Now loop your result and add it to List of `Result`

```
 ArrayList<Result> result = new ArrayList<>();
  for(int i=0 ;i < listPage.size() ;i++){
     Page page = listPage.get(i);
     Tag tag = tagList.get(i);
     result.setPage(page);
     result.setTag(tag);
  }
```

In your adapter change `Page` to `Result`

```
tvTitreList.setText(getItem(position).getPage().getTitrePage());
tvDateList.setText(getItem(position).getPage().getDatePage().toString());
tvTagList.setText(getItem(position).getTag().getTextTag());
```

Comment: I have edited my code with you're method check my edit

Answer (score 0):

Finally it's ok with your method I have changed some code.
thanks to you @rajan ks

```
pageMgr  = new PageMgr(this);
            lvList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listPage);

            ArrayList<Page> listPage = pageMgr.getAllPageArray();
            ArrayList<Tag> listTag = pageMgr.getAllTagArray();
            ArrayList<PageTag> pageTag = new ArrayList<>();

            for(int i = 0 ;i < listPage.size() ;i++) {

                Page page = listPage.get(i);
                Tag tag = listTag.get(i);
                PageTag pageT = new PageTag(page, tag);
                pageTag.add(pageT);
            }
                MyAdapter myAdapt = new MyAdapter(this,pageTag);
                lvList.setAdapter(myAdapt);
```